# Как сделать так чтобы бот мог отправлять многострочные сообщения

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

я пишу телеграм бота и мне нужно чтобы бот отправлял многострочное сообщение. То есть, он отправлял список игр:

```
1 игра
2 игра
3 игра
И т.д
```

Использую библиотеку телебот

Answer (score 3):

Если речь идёт о переносе строки, то достаточно добавить "\n" в текст.

```
send_message(message.chat.id, 'Игра 1\nИгра 2\nИгра 3')
```

Если же речь идёт о нескольких сообщениях, то просто несколько раз прописать команду по отправке сообщения send_message().

Comment: Бот выводит /n как сообщение

Comment: Вводите обратный слэш (\n)? Если вводить /n - будет читаться как обычный текст.

Answer (score 0):

Это можно реализовать двумя способами (способов много, но эти самые простые)

**1 способ**

```
mess = 'Игра 1\nИгра 2\nИгра 3'
send_message(message.chat.id, mess)
```

**2 способ**

```
mess = 'Игра 1\n' \
       'Игра 2\n' \
       'Игра 3\n'
send_message(message.chat.id, mess)
```